# How to assign value to readonly field in an abstract class?

Tags: c#, class, abstract

I have a field in base abstract class. I want to make this field readonly so that its value do not changed after child class has been initialized.

But abstract class cannot have constructor and readonly can only be initialized from constructor.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could for instance call a the constructor of your base class from the child class constructor like this:

Readonly field and constructor in base class:

```
public readonly int MyInt;

protected TheBaseClass(int myInt)
{
    this.MyInt = myInt;
}
```

Constructors in child class:

```
public TheChildClass() : base(42)
{
}

public TheChildClass(int i) : base(i)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the right pattern ;). Note: the child class can be abstract, too.

Comment: Aliostad beat me to it, but I leave this answer too, as it's a small variation where you call the base class constructor with a parameter from the child class constructor.

Comment: You could expand this, and propagate the parameterized ctor like this: `public TheChildClass(int i) : base(i) { ... }`

Comment: @Abel: true indeed. I'll update the answer to show that option too :)

Answer (score 6):

`abstract` class **can** have constructor.

```
public abstract class MyAbstract
{

    protected readonly string SomeField;

    public MyAbstract()
    {
        SomeField = "Some";
    }
}

public abstract class MyInheited
{


    public MyInheited(): base()
    {
    }
}
```

If I were you I would have the field **not readonly protected field** but expose it as **public readonly property**

Comment: Why? Perfectly valid reasons to have `protected` `readonly` fields. E.g. wanting to hide `DbContext` object in a service layer's API.

Comment: I would make a suggestion here to make the constructor in the abstract class `internal` or `protected`, since it can't be instantiated anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes CAN have a constructor, they can simply not be initiated.